# Refactor overriden methods, which have difference only in the middle of the body

Tags: java, refactoring, dry

Sometimes methods have the only difference somwhere in the middles of their bodies and it's difficult to generalize them or extract common part of code to a single method.

**Question itself:** How would you refactor the following implementations of interface methods to avoid duplicate code around `for` loop body?

```
interface MyInterface {
    Integer myInterfaceMethod(String inputStr);
    Integer myInterfaceOtherMethod(String inputStr)
}

class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    public Integer myInterfaceMethod(String inputStr) {
        @Override
        try {
            List<String> listDependingOnString = getListByString(inputStr);
            Integer result = -1;
            if (inputStr != null) {
                result = 0;
                for (String str : listDependingOnString) {

                    // Some different code, given just for example
                    result += str.length();

                }
            }

            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            exceptionProcessing(e);

            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Integer myInterfaceOtherMethod(String inputStr) {
        try {
            List<String> listDependingOnString = getListByString(inputStr);
            Integer result = -1;
            if (inputStr != null) {
                result = 0;
                for (String str : listDependingOnString) {

                    // Some different code, given just for example
                    System.out.println(str);
                    ++result;

                }
            }

            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            exceptionProcessing(e);

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For this particular example, a lambda would work nicely:

```
private Integer computeStringFunction(String inputStr, BiFunction<Integer,String,Integer> accumulator) {
    try {
        List<String> listDependingOnString = getListByString(inputStr);
        Integer result = -1;
        if (inputStr != null) {
            result = 0;
            for (String str : listDependingOnString) {
                result = accumulator.apply(result, str);
            }
        }

        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        exceptionProcessing(e);

        return null;
    }

public Integer myInterfaceMethod(String inputStr) {
    return computeStringFunction(inputStr,
        (Integer oldValue, String str) -> oldValue + str.length());
}

public Integer myInterfaceOtherMethod(String inputStr) {
    return computeStringFunction(inputStr,
        (Integer oldValue, String str) -> {
             System.out.println(str);
             return oldValue + 1;
        });
}
```

"accumulator" here is a function that takes an integer and a string and returns another integer, and whose intent is to keep a "running total" of some sort.

[BiFunction documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html)

**Note:** not tested

Answer (score 2):

The key to remove `duplicate pattern` in codes is to abstract the common part to one place and then find a way to pass the different part of `"code pieces"` as parameters to execute, for languages in which function is first class citizen(JavaScript, Python), you can always wrap the `"code pieces"` as functions. But it's not applicable for Java because method in Java is not a value, one way to resolve it is to define `interface`s, and then pass the instance of a class which implements the `interface` as parameters, with `lambda expression` in `Java 8` it can be more simpler.

Take the code in question as example, the `common pattern` is:

- iterate the list and process each item
- accumulate the result of each item and return

Then we can define two interfaces:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ItemHandler<T, R> {
    /**
     * Takes input item of type T, then returns result of type R
     */
    R handle(T t);
}
```

And another `interface` to accumulate the result:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ItemResultAccumulator<T> {
    T accumulate(T t1, T t2);
}
```

and then your code could be refactored as(*I removed all exception handling and `null` checking code, to make the code less verbose to view*):

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    private static final ItemResultAccumulator<Integer> ADDER = (t1, t2) -> t1 + t2;

    @Override
    public Integer myInterfaceMethod(String inputStr) {
        return processList(getListByString(inputStr), s -> s.length(), ADDER); 
    }

    @Override
    public Integer myInterfaceOtherMethod(String inputStr) {
        return processList(getListByString(inputStr), s -> {
            System.out.println(s);
            return Integer.valueOf(1);
        }, ADDER);
    }

    private Integer processList(List<String> list, ItemHandler<String, Integer> handler, ItemResultAccumulator<Integer> accumulator) {
        Integer result = 0;
        if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
            for (String item : list) {
                result = accumulator.accumulate(result, handler.handle(item));
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private List<String> getListByString(String inputStr) {
        // Your logic to generate list by input
        return Lists.newArrayList(inputStr.split(","));
    }
}
```

This is a little of my thinking of this problem, hope this could be helpful:-)